# Ajuda para entender erro de uso de hash

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um programa para ler as palavras de um arquivo de texto, gerando um código hash para usar como índice que irá guardar a palavra em um vetor que cabe ate 1000 palavras.

Função que gera o nº hash:

```
int a, i,j,soma = 0;
i = strlen(str);
j = 1;
char * c;
for(a = 0; a< i; a++){
    soma += (int)str[a] * pow(7, j);
    j++;
}
soma = soma%1000;
printf("Hash: %d\n", soma);
return soma;
```

A `struct` do Vetor:

```
typedef struct vetor{  
    char * palavra;  
}Vetor;
```

E o código:

```
char word[1000];
Vetor * vet = (Vetor *)malloc(1000*sizeof(Vetor));

FILE * file;
file = fopen("teste.txt", "r");


while(fgets(word, 1000, file) != NULL){
    char * p;
    p = strtok(word, " \n \r \t");
    while(p != NULL){
        strupr(p);
        int hashPos;
        hashPos = geraHash(p);

        printf("Palavra: %s  Hash: %d\n",p, hashPos);
        printf("\n");

        vet[hashPos].palavra = p;


        p = strtok(NULL, " \n \r \t");
    }
}

    printf(" %s " , vet[670].palavra);
    printf(" %s " , vet[801].palavra);
    printf(" %s " , vet[867].palavra);
    printf(" %s " , vet[846].palavra);


fclose(file);
```

O arquivo de texto teste.txt contém apenas as linhas: 1ª: "abc def" e 2ª: "asd cd".
Saída:
[image: Essa é a saída do programa]

Não estou entendendo porque aparece a mesma palavra em duas posições diferentes geradas pela função hash. Alguém saberia me dizer onde estou errando?

Answer (score 0):

O problema está relacionado com a forma com o `strtok` funciona e com o facto de você estar a guardar o ponteiro original devolvido pelo `strtok`.

Atente na reserva que a [documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) faz em relação à string passada ao `strtok`:

> Notice that this string is modified by being broken into smaller strings (tokens).

Ou seja a string passada é modificada, e por isso quando guarda a palavra:

```
vet[hashPos].palavra = p;
```

Está a atribuir o ponteiro de uma string que vai ser modificada pelo `strtok`.

A solução passa por criar uma string duplicada daquela em que vai. Existe já uma função para fazer isso, a [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup), que aloca o espaço necessário para a string com `malloc`. Isto implica que se já não precisar destas strings tem de fazer `free` sobre elas para não ter nenhum vazamento de memoria.

Precisa então apenas de alterar a instrução que guarda a palavra para:

```
vet[hashPos].palavra = strdup(p);
```

Naturalmente poderia fazer a duplicação à mão à custa de `malloc`, `strlen` e `strcpy`:

```
vet[hashPos].palavra = malloc(sizeof(strlen(p) + 1)); // +1 para o terminador
strcpy(vet[hashPos].palavra, p);
```

Exemplo de execução na minha máquina:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Entendi. Fiz como sugerido e realmente funcionou. Muito Obrigado pelo esclarecimento!